# Styling in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have recently started my adventure with xamarin forms. Please help with styles. In xamarin native, I created a custom style for the button in a separate file and added it to xaml using:

```
style="@style/button_style"

<style name="button_style" >
    <item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:gravity" >center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin" >3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize" >18dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor" >@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx" >1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy" >1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius" >2</item>
</style>
```

Thanks to this I was able to use a shadow for the text. What do I have to do to get this effect in xamarin forms?

Picture for native:

[image]

Picture for Forms:

[image]

Comment: You could check out the documentation about styling using [XAML Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Xamarin Community Toolkit` to achieve this.

First, Adding the Nuget Packagefrom NuGet Package the plugin: Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.

Second, Adding the Namespace: `xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"`

Third, Add the code to the button:

```
<Button
xct:ShadowEffect.Color="Red"
xct:ShadowEffect.OffsetY="5"
xct:ShadowEffect.OffsetX="5"
xct:ShadowEffect.Radius="10"/>
```